# An element of order $n$ generates a normal subgroup of $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

> Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ of $D_n$. Show that $\langle a\rangle \lhd D_n$ and $D_n/\langle a\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_2$.

Proof: Let $K = <a>$ for some a ∈ G. Let H ≤ K be an arbitrary subgroup. Since
$H ≤ K = <a>$ it follows that $H = <a^d>$ for some integer d.
If |a| = 1 then a = 1, H = K = {1} and, obviously, $H \lhd G$.

Is what I have right? I think to prove the second part I use Lagrange but I'm not sure how.

Comment: What is $D_n$? Is it the dihedral group of order $2n$?  If so, then $\langle a \rangle$ has order $n$ and hence is normal since it has index 2.  But then the quotient group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, not $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: I can't see what you are trying to prove. It seems to me that you are checking if the subgroup is a minimal non-trivial subgroup. How would you check a group is a normal subgroup? People already pointed out that a subgroup of index $2$ is a normal subgroup. Could you try to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D_n$ is the dihedral group, then it has $2n$ elements. It is a general fact that every subgroup of order $n$ is normal.

Comment: Or more generally, any subgroup of a group of index 2 is normal.

Comment: So how would this show that the quotient is isomorphic to $Z_2$

Comment: As a set the quotient has 2 elements. Thus it must be $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Proof: $D_n$ is the dihedral group that has 2n elements. We know that any subgroup of index 2 is normal so $<a> \lhd D_n$ (proved that a subgroup of a group of index 2 is normal in another homework problem). This means $D_n/<a> $ has 2 elements which is isomorphic to $Z_2$, the unique group order 2. Thus, $D_n/<a> \cong Z_2$.     Is this fine?